i am experiencing numpy problem how can i fix it?
A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in
NumPy 2.1.1 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x
versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0.
Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11\>=2.12'.

If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy\<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\\Users\\jordy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EA bot\\hft.py", line 1, in \<module\>
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
File "C:\\Users\\jordy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EA bot\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\MetaTrader5\__init_\_.py", line 258, in \<module\>
from .\_core import \*
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\jordy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EA bot\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core_multiarray_umath.py", line 44, in __getattr__
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in
NumPy 2.1.1 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x
versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0.
Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11\>=2.12'.

If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy\<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\jordy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EA bot\\hft.py", line 1, in \<module\>
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
File "C:\\Users\\jordy\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EA bot\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\MetaTrader5\__init_\_.py", line 258, in \<module\>
from .\_core import \*
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

I tried downgrading numpy but still the same thing

Have you tried the suggestions in this thread? https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/384382
